Error when calling renderPdfForOrder() in Module
The error I'm receiving is:
Call to a member function getRenderLanguage() on null

My Code (Edit - simplified):
 $mergeService = new Merger();
 $batchFileName = 'VAT-' . $country . ( $date ? '-' . $date : '');
 foreach ($orders as $order) {
   $orderPdf = Commerce::getInstance()->getPdfs()->renderPdfForOrder($order, '', null);
   $mergeService->addRaw($orderPdf);
 }
 $batchPdf = $mergeService->merge();


I got in touch with Craft support and this was a bug that the Craft Commerce team fixed in Craft v4. They were kind enough to backport the fix to v3. Should work for anyone else moving forward!

According to the error, the issue is that $pdf is null... so maybe the variable name is wrong, or there's some other upstream issue that's causing $pdf to not exist.
